# onclicklistener on a viewgroup with its child views

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a relative layout that I want to make tappable, including its child views.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/houses_rel_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_bottom">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/houses_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TextView... />
    .....
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: layout]

I want to set an onclicklistener on the relative layout, the horizontal view, and the textviews, and a separate onclicklistener on the icon.

```
@BindView(R.id.houses_rel_1)
ViewGroup mHouse;

@BindView(R.id.fav_icn_1)
ImageView mFavIcn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_house_list);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    mHouse.setOnClickListener(new ViewGroup.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SomeActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    mFavIcn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ...
    });
}
```

Currently, the new activity is staring only when I tap on the `textview`s, but nothing happens when I tap on the `horizontalscrollview`. Do I have to duplicate the onclicklistener to `horizontalscrollview`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `setOnTouchListener()` on `horizontalScrollView` instead of `setOnClickListener()`.

Mmmmmm...The reason is very complicated. After I read the source code of `HorizontalScrollView.java`, I found it overrides these methods of `View` or `ViewGroup`--`onTouchEvent`, `onInterceptTouchEvent`.Without use `super.onTouchEvent`,`super.onInterceptTouchEvent`.It partly means if you set a OnClickListener on it(`HorizontalScrollView`), the `onClick` event will never be invoked.

If you want to know more about, you can read the source code too. It will more helpful then I telling you the reason, cuz I may have some misinterpretations in reading.

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try grouped onClick of Butter Knife :

```
@OnClick({ R.id.houses_1, R.id.houses_rel_1 })
public void startSomeActivity() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SomeActivity.class);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```